# Ender's Game movie Battle School dimensions and floor plan?

Tags: movie, enders-game, map, space-station

Do a floorplan, dimensions, rotation rates, max population, docking specs etc. exist for the Battle School space station in the 2013 movie version of Ender's Game?

I've found a few deductions based on what is visible on screen so far: http://artofdarian.blogspot.dk/2012/07/enders-game-movie-battle-school.html
I'm hoping for more. Thanks.

Comment: The Shadow series mentions three rotating rings each with ~16 levels, if I recall. Gym is on the outside/bottom floor, battle rooms are in the middle.